# Aumentar quantidade de um produto

Tags: php

```html
<div class="button2">

<?php

while($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
  $resultado1 = $row1[1];
  $resultado2 = $row1[0];
  $id1[$i] = $resultado2;
  $nome[$i] = $resultado1;
?>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit" class="bt5" value="<?php echo $resultado1;?>" name="botoes">
</form>

<?php
  $i = $i + 1;
}
?>
</div>

<?php
}

else {
  header("Location: index.php");
}

if(isset($_POST["botoes"])){
  $cookiebotao_value = $_POST["botoes"];
  setcookie("erbonsoftwarebotao", $cookiebotao_value);
  setcookie("erbonsoftwarerefresh", 1);
  header("Location: banquetes.php?id=$id");
}

if(isset($_POST["botoes2"])){
  $contagem = $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarecontagem"];
  $contagem = $contagem + 1; 
  setcookie("erbonsoftwarecontagem", $contagem);
  $cookiebotao2_value = $_POST["botoes2"];
  setcookie("erbonsoftwarenome$contagem", $cookiebotao2_value);
  setcookie("erbonsoftwarerefresh", 1);
  header("Location: banquetes.php?id=$id");
}
?>
<div class="button3">
<?php
  $repeticoes = "";
  setcookie("erbonsoftwarerepeticoes", "");
 
  if(isset($_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarerefresh"]) && $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarerefresh"] == 1) {
  if(isset($_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarebotao"]) && $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarebotao"] !== "" ) {
  setcookie("erbonsoftwarerefresh", 0);
  $nome1 = $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarebotao"];
   
  for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j ++) {
if($nome[$j] == $nome1) {
  $idcampo = $id1[$j];
  setcookie("erbonsoftwareidcampo", $idcampo);
     
  $sql2 = "SELECT S.id AS Id, S.idServiceAccounts AS IdServiceAccount, 
     SR.idServiceDepartments AS IdDepartment, 
     S.[description] AS [Description], (CASE WHEN SR.priceSale = 0 OR SR.priceSale is null 
     THEN S.priceSale ELSE SR.priceSale END) 
            AS Price, S.icms AS Tax6, S.iss AS Tax1, S.ir AS Tax2, S.csll AS Tax3, 
     S.pis AS Tax4, S.cofins AS Tax5, S.isProductKitchen AS IsProductKitchen, 
     S.isServiceTax AS IsServiceTax, PrinterConfig.printerKitchen1 AS PrinterKitchen1, 
     PrinterConfig.printerKitchen1FonteTicket AS PrinterKitchen1Font, 
     PrinterConfig.printerKitchen2 AS PrinterKitchen2, 
     PrinterConfig.printerKitchen2FonteTicket AS PrinterKitchen2Font, 
     PrinterConfig.printerKitchen3 AS PrinterKitchen3, 
     PrinterConfig.printerKitchen3FonteTicket AS PrinterKitchen3Font 
     FROM Services S INNER JOIN ServicesDepartmentsRelationship SR ON S.id = SR.idServices 
     AND SR.isActive = 1 AND SR.idServiceDepartments = (SELECT P.idDepartment 
     FROM PointOfSale P WHERE P.id = ".$id.") 
     LEFT JOIN ServicesPointOfSalePrinterKitchen Printer ON S.id=Printer.idProduct 
     AND Printer.isActive = 1 AND Printer.idPointOfSale = ".$id." 
     LEFT JOIN ServicesPrinterKitchen PrinterConfig 
     ON Printer.idServicesPrinterKitchen = PrinterConfig.id  WHERE S.isActive = 1 
     AND S.isProduct = 1 AND S.idPointOfSaleCategoryProduct = ".$idcampo." 
     ORDER BY S.description ASC";
      
     $result2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);
     $repeticoes = 0;
      
   while($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result2, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
$repeticoes = $repeticoes + 1;
$resultado3 = $row2[3];
$resultado4 = $row2[4];
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="bt6" value="<?php echo $resultado3;echo " R$ ";echo $resultado4;?>"name="botoes2">       
</form>
<?php
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
?>
</div>
<div class="totaldebotoes">
 <div class="button4">
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarecontagem"]) && $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarecontagem"] !== "") { 
   $for = $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarecontagem"];
   
if(isset($_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarenome1"]) && $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarenome1"] !== "") {
   for($p = 0; $p < $for; $p ++) {
?>
 <div class="caixa">
    <div class="nome">
<?php
  $p1 = $p + 1;
  $resposta1 = "0";
  $resposta2 = "0";
  $resposta3 = "0";
  $resposta4 = "0";
  $p5 = "0";
       
  for($p2 = 0; $resposta1 == "0"; $p2 ++) {
  if($_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarenome$p1"][$p2] == "R" && $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarenome$p1"][$p2 + 1] == "$") {
     $resposta1 = "1";       
  }
        
  else {
     echo $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarenome$p1"][$p2];
  }
 }
?>
</div>
<div class="quantidade">
<?php
 for($p4 = 0; $p4 <= $p; $p4 ++) {
 if($nome[$p] == $nome[$p4]) {
 if(isset($quantidade[$p4]) && $quantidade[$p4] !== "") {
    $quantidade[$p4] = $quantidade[$p4] + 1;
 }
         
 else {
  $quantidade[$p4] = "1";
 }
}
        
else {
}
   }
       
   echo $quantidade[$p];
?>
</div>
<div class="preco">
<?php
   for($p3 = 0; $resposta2 == "0"; $p3 ++) {
 if($resposta3 == 0) {
    if($_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarenome$p1"][$p3] == "R" && $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarenome$p1"][$p3 + 1] == "$") {
  $resposta3 = "1";       
 }
         
 else {
 }
}

if($resposta3 == 1) {
   if($resposta4 == 3) {
     $resposta2 = "1";
 }
         
 else {
    echo $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarenome$p1"][$p3];
          
    if($resposta4 == 1 || $resposta4 == 2) {
  $resposta4 = $resposta4 + 1;
 }
}
         
          
if(isset($_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarenome$p1"][$p3]) && $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarenome$p1"][$p3] !== "" ) { 
           
 if($_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarenome$p1"][$p3] == "." ) { 
 $resposta4 = $resposta4 + 1;
}
   }
  }
 }
?>
</div>     
<div class="remover">
   <form action="" method="post">
 <button type="submit" class="bt7"name="<?php echo $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarenome$p1"]?>">Remover</button>      
   </form>
 </div>
 </div>
<?php
 }
}
   }
?>
 </div>
 <div class="button5">
  <input type="submit" class="bt8" value="Observações da camada" name="apagar">
 </div>
 <div class="precototal">
  <h3 class="textototal">Total</h3>
<?php
  if(isset($_COOKIE["erbonsoftwaretotalpedido"]) && $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwaretotalpedido"] !== "") { 
   $total = $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwaretotalpedido"];
  }
  
  else {
   $total = "0";
  }
  
  if(isset($_COOKIE["erbonsoftwaren1"]) && $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwaren1"] !== "") { 
   $n1 = $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwaren1"];
  }
  
  else {
   $n1 = "0";
  }
  
  if(isset($_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarecontagem"]) && $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarecontagem"] !== "") { 
  $for = $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarecontagem"];
    
  if(isset($_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarenome1"]) && $_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarenome1"] !== "") {
  for($p = 0; $p < $for; $p ++) {
   $p1 = $p + 1;
      
   $sql3 = "SELECT S.id AS Id, S.idServiceAccounts AS IdServiceAccount, SR.idServiceDepartments AS IdDepartment, 
   S.[description] AS [Description], (CASE WHEN SR.priceSale = 0 OR SR.priceSale is null THEN S.priceSale ELSE SR.priceSale END) AS Price, S.icms AS Tax6, S.iss AS Tax1, S.ir AS Tax2, S.csll AS Tax3, S.pis AS Tax4, S.cofins AS Tax5, S.isProductKitchen AS IsProductKitchen, S.isServiceTax AS IsServiceTax, PrinterConfig.printerKitchen1 AS PrinterKitchen1, PrinterConfig.printerKitchen1FonteTicket AS PrinterKitchen1Font, PrinterConfig.printerKitchen2 AS PrinterKitchen2, PrinterConfig.printerKitchen2FonteTicket AS PrinterKitchen2Font, PrinterConfig.printerKitchen3 AS PrinterKitchen3, PrinterConfig.printerKitchen3FonteTicket AS PrinterKitchen3Font FROM Services S INNER JOIN ServicesDepartmentsRelationship SR ON S.id = SR.idServices AND SR.isActive = 1 AND SR.idServiceDepartments = (SELECT P.idDepartment FROM PointOfSale P WHERE P.id = ".$id.")  LEFT JOIN ServicesPointOfSalePrinterKitchen Printer ON S.id=Printer.idProduct  AND Printer.isActive = 1 AND Printer.idPointOfSale = ".$id." LEFT JOIN ServicesPrinterKitchen PrinterConfig ON Printer.idServicesPrinterKitchen = PrinterConfig.id WHERE S.isActive = 1 and S.isProduct = 1 AND S.idPointOfSaleCategoryProduct = ".$_COOKIE["erbonsoftwareidcampo"]." ORDER BY S.description ASC";
$result3 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql3);
      
while($row3 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result3, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
 $resultado5 = $row3[3];
 $resultado6 = $row3[4];
       
 if($p == $n1) {
 if($_COOKIE["erbonsoftwarenome$p1"] == $somar) {
  $total = $total + $resultado6;
  $n1 = $n1 + 1;
          
 }
        
 else {
  }
       }
       }
      }
     }
    }
  }
?>
  <div class="soma">
   <h3 class="textototal"><?php echo $total?>&nbsp;</h3>
   <h1>$</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Boa tarde, tenho o código abaixo e preciso de fazer com que a quantidade aumente, ou seja, tenho uma lista de produtos e ao clicar a quantidade "1" não passa para "2".

Comment: Clicar onde????

Comment: @RFL código atualizado

Comment: Não consegui entender direito sua pergunta

Comment: @gabrielfalieri eu estou a fazer uma lista de compras, e quando clico num produto aparece ao lado, mas se quiser mais quantidade desse produto, em vez de o número aumentar, o mesmo produto fica em lista, ou seja, aparece por baixo

Comment: Indica algum erro?

Comment: @gabrielfalieri não, apenas não aumenta à quantidade